# Client can't find endpoint element of WCF Inside Windows Service

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services, wcf-binding

I'm trying to put a WCF service inside a Windows Service.  I used svcutil to use the CalculatorService.cs and output.config.  I put the contents of the output.config into the App.config and write a client, including the CalculatorService.cs into it.  When it runs, I get the error, "Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'IAnswerResult' in the ServiceModel client configuration section".  In my client, I've just copied what the wizard said to use:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
AnswerResultClient client = new AnswerResultClient(); // error here
client.QuestionAnswered("1", "2", "3");
}
```

In App.config of the client (generated) I have the following but it tells me that the contract "IAnswerResult" is invalid.  I don't know why... it's what was generated by svcutil.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IAnswerResult" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IAnswerResult" />
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:6255/CalculatorService" binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IAnswerResult" contract="IAnswerResult"
          name="BasicHttpBinding_IAnswerResult" />
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:6256/CalculatorService"
          binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IAnswerResult"
          contract="IAnswerResult" name="NetTcpBinding_IAnswerResult">
        <identity>
          <servicePrincipalName value="host/Server2012" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Code in the Windows Service/WCF Service:

```
namespace EternaService
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://EternaService")]

    public interface IAnswerResult
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string QuestionAnswered(string person_int, string course_int, string lesson_int);
    }


    public class CalculatorService : IAnswerResult
    {
        public string QuestionAnswered(string person_int, string course_int, string lesson_int)
        {
            string result = "";
            // Have input, now do something with it.
            return result;
        }

    }

    public partial class EternaService : ServiceBase
    {
        public ServiceHost serviceHost = null;

        public EternaService()
        {
            this.CanStop = true;
            this.CanHandlePowerEvent = true;
            this.CanHandleSessionChangeEvent = true;
            this.CanPauseAndContinue = true;
            this.CanShutdown = true;

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {

            if (serviceHost != null)
            {
                serviceHost.Close();
            }
            serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(CalculatorService));
            serviceHost.Open();
        }
```

App.config in the Windows Service/WCF Service:

```
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="EternaService.CalculatorService" behaviorConfiguration="myServiceBehave">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:6255/CalculatorService"/>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:6256/CalculatorService"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:6255/CalculatorService" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="EternaService.IAnswerResult" />
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:6256/CalculatorService" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="EternaService.IAnswerResult" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="myServiceBehave">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Any direction greatly appreciated.  This is my first attempt and I'm lost!

EDIT:
I changed the Windows service ServiceContract namespace to:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://CADEEternaService")]
```

In the client CalculatorService class:

```
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace= "http://CADEEternaService", ConfigurationName="IAnswerResult")]
public interface IAnswerResult
{

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action= "http://CADEEternaService/IAnswerResult/QuestionAnswered", ReplyAction= "http://CADEEternaService/IAnswerResult/QuestionAnsweredResponse")]
    string QuestionAnswered(string person_int, string course_int, string lesson_int);

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action= "http://CADEEternaService/IAnswerResult/QuestionAnswered", ReplyAction= "http://CADEEternaService/IAnswerResult/QuestionAnsweredResponse")]
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> QuestionAnsweredAsync(string person_int, string course_int, string lesson_int);
}
```

In the client's app.config:

```
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:6255/CalculatorService" binding="basicHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IAnswerResult" contract="CADEEternaService.IAnswerResult"
      name="BasicHttpBinding_IAnswerResult" />
  <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:6256/CalculatorService"
      binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IAnswerResult"
      contract="CADEEternaService.IAnswerResult" name="NetTcpBinding_IAnswerResult">
```

But it's still flagging "CADEEternaService.IAnswerResult" as an error and I'm also getting the original error, "Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'IAnswerResult'"... however, I find it odd that it's barking at IAnswerResult and not CADEEternaService.IAnswerResult in the error message.

Comment: I changed both contract values to "EternaService.IAnswerResult" but it's giving the same error, "Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'IAnswerResult' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element."  I tried using Inelllisense and it finds nothing I recognize.

Comment: Note that the namespace you set on the `ServiceContract` has no bearing on the namespace of the contract.   The service contract namespace is part of SOAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the namespace of your Service Reference generated, before the contract ....
**contract="xxxxxxx.IAnswerResult**

```
 <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IAnswerResult" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IAnswerResult" />
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:6255/CalculatorService" binding="basicHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IAnswerResult" contract="**xxxxx.IAnswerResult**"
      name="BasicHttpBinding_IAnswerResult" />
  <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:6256/CalculatorService"
      binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IAnswerResult"
      contract="IAnswerResult" name="NetTcpBinding_IAnswerResult">
    <identity>
      <servicePrincipalName value="host/Server2012" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
</client>
```

Comment: As I said above, a fully qualified name still gives an error.  In looking at app.config, if I hover over the contract value, it says "The contract value is invalid according to its datatype 'clientContractType' - the enumeration constraint failed"

Comment: Try to change the namespace to a different one that is not in your project namespace EternaService
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://EternaService")] Your namespace is the same to your service name.

Comment: I thought you were on to something... unless I messed up the changes.  I edited the original post using CADEEternaService as the contract namespace.

Comment: In your client app you need to add a reference to your WCF Service Library project from your Windows service and add the following using statements to the **.cs file in your Windows service project. Try to follow this tutorial https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649818.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: The key was the reference to the WCF Serivce in the client.  Oddly, I created the ServiceReference ok but couldn't get it to show with a "using".  So I fully qualified it with:
CalculatorServiceReference.AnswerResultClient client = new CalculatorServiceReference.AnswerResultClient("NetTcpBinding_IAnswerResult");

Answer (score 0):

In your client's config, the contract needs to be a fully qualified name, not just the interface name.

```
<endpoint address="http://localhost:6255/CalculatorService" 
          binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IAnswerResult" 
          contract="EternaService.IAnswerResult"
          name="BasicHttpBinding_IAnswerResult" />
  <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:6256/CalculatorService"
            binding="netTcpBinding" 
            bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IAnswerResult"
            contract="EternaService.IAnswerResult"
            name="NetTcpBinding_IAnswerResult">
```

In other words, `EternaServie.IAnswerResult`, not just `IAnswerResult`.